# How to invoke crystal reports from powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: crystal-reports, powerbuilder

We need to call crystal reports from powerbuilder 12.5

Can anyone point to some example source code for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.general/-tPI21V0tv4) has a code sample of how to call a CR from version 11.5. I'm not very familiar with power builder, but I can't imagine the syntax from 11.5 to 12.5 is much different.